# glBlend and strange effect for overlapping geometry

Tags: opengl-es

Suppose I have two squares which have the same *y* value and which partially overlap in the *xz* plane. I want to use alpha blending,

```
    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

so that parts of the textures mapped to the square geometry are transparent (depending on what the alpha values are)

However, because the y values are the some, when rendering there are strange visual effects (all I can describe the effect as is "shredded" looking or in some cases one texture obscures the other).

If I "separate" the two squares so that the y values are 0 and 0.1, this effect goes away. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening without having to "separate" the squares?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try disabling DepthTest

Answer (score 0):

In case others are having the same problem, the following worked for me:

```
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        // draw here...
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Easy once you know.